# Is this a violation of Normal Form?

Tags: normalization

Assume a cash register system where some users have access to a cash drawer, while others do not (they can only close by some kind of card payment).  Keep in mind that a user who closes a check a one time may have access to the cash drawer, but later they may not.

There is a table called `check` with a column of `closedAtDeviceId`.

While a check is open, `closedAtDeviceId` is null.

If a check is closed by a user that has access to the cash drawer, the column `closedAtDeviceId` is populated with the id of the cash drawer.  This would include if a check is closed by debit, credit, or gift card.

If a check is closed by a user that does not have access to the cash drawer the column in question is assigned the id of the scanner.

Is this a horrible hack?  Yes.
Could this be solved with reasonable DB design?  Yes.
Is this a real world example?  Its to wacky to be conceived in theory.

Is this a violation of some level of normal form?

Comment: The normal forms are for describing how data is related to one another with a goal towards minimizing data duplication.  What you are describing is business/application logic for how to interpret what "closedAtDeviceId" means.  It's probably not the best way to do that because you are overloading the meaning of the field but as long as it's understood and consistent then there shouldn't be any problems.

Comment: +1 @JonathanFite, One way to improve the likelihood that this concept is understood and used consistently is for the `Devices` table to indicate that the device doesn't have a cash drawer.  Adding a `bit` field would be a nice compromise for you and the original designer to reach.